# What is wrong with the query?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm implementing this query with `asp.net` in `VB`, the objective of that query is to sort out the email data other than `@yahoo.com` and `@gmail.com`, it shows an error :

Incorrect syntax near '@yahoo' and '@gmail".

```
"select * from print_venue where not (email_id like %" & "@yahoo.com" & "%) AND (email_id like %" & "@gmail.com" & "%)"
```

What's wrong with the above query ?

Comment: it's missing single quotes in filter for email_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the quotes around the `like` statement

```
"select * from print_venue 
where not (email_id like '%" & "@yahoo.com" & "%') 
AND (email_id like '%" & "@gmail.com" & "%')"
```

It has to be

```
email_id like '%@yahoo.com%'
```

and not

```
email_id like %@yahoo.com%
```

Comment: Juergen when i paster your code in my select query in VB.net is shows the blue line under it

Comment: I think you need to put a backlash \ before each '

Comment: @MiquelColl You do not need to escape the string with backslashes

Comment: Okay, so it was the starting " then? Sorry.